# Ignore priority 3,4,5 violations in gradle pmd plugin

Tags: gradle, pmd

I want my gradle pmd plugin to fail my build only if there are violations with priority 1 and 2. I don't want to fail the build if there are only violations with priority 3, 4 and 5. Is there a way to achieve same? I went through the gradle pmd plugin documentation and couldn't find anything there.

Presently, my `build.gradle` has following code:

```
pmd {
    ruleSetFiles = files('src/test/resources/ruleset.xml')
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be defined in `ruleset.xml` file?

Comment: in ruleset.xml, we can only specify the priority for a rule, we can't specify if build should fail or not because of this rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can [define a config file](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/howtomakearuleset.html) which includes the rules you wish to run. You can give this file to the pmd gradle plugin.

An example file is here (`MyRules.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<ruleset name="PMD.rul" xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">

  <description>This ruleset was created from PMD.rul</description>

  <!-- We'll use the entire 'strings' ruleset -->
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml"/>

  <!-- Here's some rules we'll specify one at a time -->
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedLocalVariable"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml/UnusedPrivateField"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml/DuplicateImports"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/UnnecessaryConversionTemporary"/>

  <!-- We want to customize this rule a bit, change the message and raise the priority  -->
  <rule
   ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml/EmptyCatchBlock"
   message="Must handle exceptions">
    <priority>2</priority>
  </rule>

</ruleset>
```

The command line arguments would look like this:

```
pmd {
    ruleSetFiles = files('path/to/MyRules.xml')
}
```

This way you can define those rule violations where your build should fail.

Comment: What if I don't want to fail the build for certain violation and just want to see the violations in the report?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do that with this plugin.